# How to test DataSource method using mockito junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, datasource

I am new at testing. I have a method to test but i dont know how to do it. The method is;

```
@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource datasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Can somebody help me?